# Ruby Watir selecting text from table

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a tabbed table that I am trying to get the value from the "Active" Column for various services that are running.

```
Services
    Service                    Active
    SERVICE1                   YES
    SERVICE2                   NO
    SERVICE3                   YES
```

I was hoping to use something like this from the table. But this doesn't seem to work for me. Goal is to select one of the services and find out if it is active YES or NO and put it in a variable. You guys have been a great help to me in previous answers and I really appreciate your help and input.

```
browser.td(:text => "SERVICE1").parent.td(:index => 1).flash
```

I get an error like this when I try to use the above code

```
/home/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@vts_automated/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:490:in `assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:id=>"services", :tag_name=>"td"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

My html code looks like this

```
<table class="tabbed_table" cellspacing="5">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h2>Appliance</h2>
<dl class="table-display">
<dt class="wide">Product version: </dt>
<dd class="wide">xxxxx</dd>
<dt class="wide">Serial number:</dt>
<dd class="wide">xxxxxx</dd>
<dt class="wide">System Time:</dt>
<dd class="wide">Wednesday, October 30, 2013 02:02PM CDT</dd>
</dl>
</td>
<td>
<h2>Services</h2>
<table id="services">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Service</th>
<th>Active</th>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td class="no_bg">SERVICE1</td>
<td class="no_bg">YES</td>
</tr>
<tr class="normal">
<td class="no_bg"> SERVICE2 </td>
<td class="no_bg">NO</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td class="no_bg"> SERVICE3 </td>
<td class="no_bg">YES</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you double-check your watir code and exception? Your watir code says you are looking for `td(:text => "SERVICE1")` yet the exception suggests you are looking for something else - `{:id=>"services", :tag_name=>"td"}`.

Comment: Yeah I would ignore the watir code line I had listed. That was something I tried and did not work. td(:text => "SERVICE1").  I tried your suggestion with the collect the cells from the table method. And even though the table name is "services". It is having trouble locating this element. So now it appears it is having issue with the cells = browser.table(:id => "services").tds  line. I'm just not sure why it doesn't find this element. My watir code is cut and paste of your suggestion below.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to [collect the cells](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Container#tds-instance_method) from the table, create a hash to store the data, and then assign the data to the hash using the [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method.  At that point, you should have the data you need and can manipulate it according to your needs.  For example:

```
# get cells from table(:id => "services") 

cells = browser.table(:id => "services").tds

# create hash

service_active = {}

# iterate over cells variable using each_slice method and assign keys/values to has

cells.each_slice(2) do |slice|
  service_active["#{slice[0]}"] = slice[1]
end

# hash with data

service_active.each {|k,v| puts "the value of #{k} is #{v}"}

#=> the value of Service is Active
#=> the value of SERVICE1 is YES
#=> the value of SERVICE2 is YES
#=> the value of SERVICE3 is YES
```

Comment: Thanks I shall give this a try

Comment: Similar error to what I got earlier. It can't seem to locate the table "services" for some reason:                                 "unable to locate element, using {:id=>"services", :tag_name=>"table"} "

Comment: There is more than one table on this page so perhaps I did not cut and paste enough of the html code. I have updated the html code in the description above to hopefully make it clearer. My apologies for not capturing all of it the first time.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help.  Take a look at Justin Ko's blog post about troubleshooting the "unknown element" error: http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/troubleshooting-the-unknownobjectexception-unable-to-locate-element/.  That might help...

Comment: I ended up getting the information a different way. How do I close this post? Do I just answer my question?

Comment: Sure. Add your solution as an answer, accept it, and that should be that.